# numpy python: vectorize distance function to calculate pairwise distance of 2 matrix with a dimension of (m, 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, distance

I have two numpy arrays A and B. Shape of A is (m,3) and shape of B is (n, 3).

Those matrix look like this:

```
A
#output
array([[  9.227,  -4.698, -95.607],
   [ 10.294,  -4.659, -94.606],
   [ 11.184,  -5.906, -94.675],
   ...,
   [ 19.538, -91.572, -45.361],
   [ 20.001, -92.655, -45.009],
   [ 19.271, -92.726, -45.79 ]])
```

So it contains for each row the coordinates x,y,z of a 3D point. B follows the same format.

I have this function (np is numpy):

```
def compute_dist(point1, point2):
    squared = (point1-point2)**2
    return (np.sqrt(np.sum(squares)))
```

I want to compute a pairwise distance between A and B by using a vectorized function.

I try this:

```
 v = np.vectorize(compute_dist)
 v(A, B)
 #output
 matrix([[37.442, 42.693, 72.705],
    [37.442, 42.693, 72.705],
    [37.442, 42.693, 72.705],
    ...,
    [37.442, 42.693, 72.705],
    [37.442, 42.693, 72.705],
    [37.442, 42.693, 72.705]])
```

I don't understand how to use vectorize even if I read the doc. How can I compute a matrix which contains pairwise distance between A and B? I know there is **scipy.distance.cdist** but I want to do it myself with **np.vectorize**.

I don't care about the format of the output (list, array, matrix ...). At the end I just want to find the minimal distance.

Comment: Vectorize doesn't do what you think. What output are you expecting? An MxN matrix?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't expect any particular output. The usual form is a matrix of course. But in my code I try to get a list of all distances.

Comment: I don't necessarily mean the numbers in the output. Just the expected shape and conceptual content.

Comment: I hoped to get a list of length = m*n

Comment: Yes, It seems to me a good answer, but I need to understand it before accept it. I already upvote it because like you said it is a good introduction and well explained.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `np.newaxis` to *expand* the dimensions of your two arrays `A` and `B` to enable broadcasting and then do your calculations.

Pairwise distance means every point in `A (m, 3)` should be compared to every point in `B (n, 3)`. This results in a `(m, n)` matrix of distances.
With numpy one can use broadcasting to achieve the wanted result.
By using `A=A[:, np.newaxis, :]` and `B=B[np.newaxis, :, :]` the resulting
shapes are `A (m, 1, 3)` and `B(1, n, 3)` respectivley.
If you then perform a calculation like `C = A-B` numpy automatically
broadcasts. This means you get a copy of all m rows of A for all n columns of B
and a copy of all n columns of B for all m rows of A.

```py
  A (m, 1, 3)
- B (1, n, 3)
--------------
= C (m, n, 3)
```

To get the distance matrix you can then use `numpy.linalg.norm()`:

```py
import numpy as np
m = 10
n = 12
A = np.random.random((m, 3))
B = np.random.random((n, 3))

# Add newaxis on second axis of A and on first axis on B
C = A[:, np.newaxis, :] - B[np.newaxis, :, :]
# shape: (m, n, 3) = (m, 1, 3) - (1, n, 3)

C = np.linalg.norm(C, axis=-1)
# shape: (m, n)
```

Comment: I don't understand how it can help me. I miss something I think. Can you explain your mine?

Comment: It is not a solution using `np.vectorize`, but rather `broadcasting`. A look in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) might help you.

Comment: @Adam. This is about as spelled out as it can reasonably get. You need to sit down and walk yourself through the steps line by line. Play with each operation until you understand it. It's a painful process in the beginning, but absolutely necessary if you want to learn.

Comment: ok thanks I will check this and try to understand. I will not forget to validate the answer if I understand.

Comment: So D is a 3D matrix which contains m rows, n columns and 3 arrays ? Like we can see here https://images.app.goo.gl/Xo8dyqLaVMV3Zf7F8 ?? I think I have difficulty to represent me a 3D matrix. I don't understand how D is organized and thus how work with it...

Comment: Finally you want an `(n, m)` matrix where the `element (i, j)` stands for the scalar distance between point i of A and point j of B. As intermediate result you have an array `(m, n, 3)` where an `element (i, j, :)` stands for the distance `vector` between point i of A and point j of B.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I think I understand the organization of C matrix and how to get all distances. I will do the same instructions than you but squared ((A-B)**2) and use np.apply_over_axes(np.sum, C, 3) and then np.sqrt.

Comment: @AdamBellaïche The last line in my answer `np.linalg.norm(C, axis=-1)`does exactly that. If you want to compute it yourself its fine, but instead of using `apply_over_axis` you can just use `np.sum((A-B)**2, axis=2)`. (Remember python uses `zero based indexing`)

Comment: Oh yes indeed... Sorry I'm still little chaotic but I completely understand your answer. Thank you again.